# React native populate data after navigator.pop()

Tags: react-native

I need your help
I've main component that contains ListView with add button.
when user press add button it navigates him to add form.
then user fills the form and press save button if save process success then component run navigator.pop() to go back to main component
but ListView still dosn't update it's content
how to resolve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: You may want to add some your code, so we can help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a callback function to the navigator, when you push a component to the navigator:

```
navigator.push({
  ....
  callBack: your callback function
  ....
})
```

Then set the callback function to update the `ListView`:

```
your callback funtion(your new data){
  ....
  this.list=this.list.cloneWithRows(your new data);
  ....
}
```

Before running `navigator.pop()`, you can all the `callBack` function to update the destination `ListView` with new data:

```
 ....
 this.props.route.callBack(your new data);
 this.props.navigator.pop();
 ....
```

Hope this will help you.